# connection destroy is only working once is there a fix

Tags: javascript, discord, destroy, disconnect

Hi i have some code for my bot so it'll leave my vc when told but it works only once is there a alternative or a fix to make my bot work better? Here is my code.

````
 const discordVoice1 = require('@discordjs/voice');  
         

const connection1 = discordVoice1.joinVoiceChannel({
  
  channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
  guildId: message.member.guild.id,
  adapterCreator: message.member.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
        connection1.destroy()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code, I can only lay out the basics. but I assume you have some way of making the bot join and leave (message sent, command, etc)

```js
const {joinVoiceChannel} = require('@discordjs/voice')
const voice = require('@discordjs/voice')


// to connect
joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
    guildId: message.member.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: message.member.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
})


// to disconnect

voice.getVoiceConnection(message.member.guild.id).disconnect()
```

This code will allow infinte uses (connect, disconnect, and reconnect